# SymPy polynomials over finite fields

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials, finite-field

```
import sympy as S 
F = S.FiniteField(101)
```

When I call `f = S.poly(y ** 2 - x ** 3 - x - 1,F)` I get the following error:

> 'FiniteField' object has no attribute 'is_commutative'

But finite fields are commutative by definition! So I'm not really sure what this error is supposed to mean!

Has anyone come across this before? How do you declare polynomials over a finite field?

Comment: From my experiments you can make polynomials over finite fields with, eg., `sympy.poly(x**2 + y - 1, x, y, domain=sympy.FF(101))`. However, this seems to fail to cooperate with other sympy functionality, such as solving equations. I have opened an issue here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9821

Answer (score 1):

`is_commutative` is an attribute of [*operators*](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/search.html?q=is_commutative) generally. It is not implemented for [domains](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/tree/master/sympy/polys/domains) (unlike `is_numeric` etc).

e.g.

```py
>>> F = sympy.RealField() #returns the same error
>>> f = sympy.poly(y ** 2 - x ** 3 - x - 1, F)

AttributeError: 'RealField' object has no attribute 'is_commutative'
```

---

Hence, `poly` is interpreting your positional argument as something other than the domain. To get the intended behaviour with `poly` (and `factor` etc) you must use the [`domain`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.factor) (or equivalent) kwarg i.e:

```py
f = sympy.poly(y ** 2 - x ** 3 - x - 1, domain=F)
```